# How to apply for Europe visa for Indian staying in Australia on long-term visitor visa

Tags: visa, australia, indian-citizens, switzerland, europe

I am an Indian citizen staying in Switzerland and my parents are living with my sister in Australia for 2-3 years, on long-term visas. They are planning to visit me from Australia directly. I know the visa procedure for an Indian applying from [India](http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-application-requirements/).

I could not find procedure to apply from Australia for non-Australian. Any lead on this will be helpful.

Comment: As they're on a long-term visit visa (not really tourist), they're more of a temporary resident. Have you contacted the Embassy whether application in Australia is okay? Here's the email syd.visa@eda.admin.ch.

Comment: No problem; should you resolve this, you can come back and answer your own question (and any links etc), as it creates the resource for other. I'll upvote your question and, if you don't mind, change 'tourist' to 'visit' as it's a bit more accurate.